# How to marshall and unmarshall Object-type fields?

Tags: java, marshalling, xstream, unmarshalling

I've got an interface with a generic method

```
public interface A {
  public void setValue(Object value);
  public Object getValue();
  }
```

A class that implements this interface but restrict the value to some specific enum class (eg values are X,Y,Z):

```
public class B implements A {
  private MyEnum value=null;
  public Object getValue() { return value; }
  public void setValue(Object value) { 
    if (!(value instanceof MyEnum)) throw IllegalArgumentException(...);
    this.value=(MyEnum)value;
    }
  }
```

For the marshalling and unmarshalling, I wrote a specific converter
For the marshalling I have

```
public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
    return A.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}

public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
    ...
    A entry = (A) source;
    writer.startNode("value");
    context.convertAnother(entry.getValue());
    writer.endNode();
    ...
}
```

This would produce for an instance of class B

```
...
    <value>X</value>
...
```

**XStream does not add any instruction about the class of this field**. Just the string value of the enum.

For the unmarshalling I have:

```
public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
  ...
  reader.moveDown();
  Object type = context.convertAnother(extra, Object.class);
  extra.setValue(type);
  reader.moveUp();
  ...
  return extra;
}
```

I put `Object.class` because I don't know which object-type it contains. I expected XStream to add some information about that.

And this fails because `Object type = context.convertAnother(extra, Object.class)` works with the "X" string and **doesn't it must produce an object of type MyEnum** which is expected by the `extra.setValue(type)`.

**How can I force or add information so that XStream knows the object-type it must produce ?**

Thanks for reading this long post...

Comment: Please show your custom converter's `canConvert()` implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default if XStream encounters an object whose class derives from a class XStream can convert, it puts the class name in a "class" attribute.

If your converters `canConvert()` returns `true` for `Object.class` then you are essentially overwriting XStream's default converter, and it's your responsibility to do what it used to do. Unless you implement a way to store type information on your own, you'll have no info about the class in the XML.

Either ditch the `A.class` / `Object.class` converter (not sure what you have since you didn't show your converter) and make converters specific to the concrete classes only (`canConvert` only returns true for `B.class`), or at least limit the damage by making a converter for the base interface instead of a general `Object.class` converter (`canConvert` returns true for `A.class.isAssignableFrom(theclass)`) in which case its up to you to decide how you want to store info about the concrete class's class in the file.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the suggestion here and added some information about the class of the value and used this to unmarshall. I am posting my working solution as a reference to any other reader that may find this question:

```
public static class ExtraSearchOptionConverter implements Converter {
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return ExtraSearchOption.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        ExtraSearchOption entry = (ExtraSearchOption) source;
        ...
        if (entry.getValue() != null) {
            writer.startNode("value");
            writer.addAttribute("class", entry.getValue().getClass().getName());
            context.convertAnother(entry.getValue());
            writer.endNode();
        }
    }
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        ExtraSearchOption extra = new ExtraSearchOption();
        ...
        if (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
            reader.moveDown();
            String className = reader.getAttribute("class");
            Class<?> valueClass = null;
            if (className != null) {
                try {
                    valueClass = Class.forName(className);
                    Object type = context.convertAnother(extra, valueClass);
                    extra.setValue(type);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    logger.error("While retrieving class for ExtraSearchOptions value", ex);
                    }
            }
            reader.moveUp();
        }

        return extra;
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks like it should work out OK. Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way! Generally, the practice here is to limit answers exclusively to answering the question, and to leave comments directly on the question itself or relevant answers. Since this post *does* contain a relevant answer, I am going to edit it to rephrase it as an answer (otherwise I would suggest removing it). Thanks! :)

Comment: (I assume that your solution is working; please confirm that this is the case so that I know the edit is good.) Mod: Please disregard pre-edit flag.